# Is it bad practice to leave the master database at a lower compatibility level after an in-place upgrade?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, amazon-rds, upgrade, aws

[Based on this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2016), Microsoft intentionally leaves the master database at the previous compatibility level after an in-place upgrade.

I recently performed an in-place upgrade from 2012 to 2017 on AWS RDS. RDS architecture does not allow its customers to be db_owner for the master database, so therefore, I cannot change the compatibility level of master to 2017 to match the rest of the system and user databases. AWS tech support has confirmed this.

Is it safe to leave it this way? Is it bad practice? Will I lose any functionality by keeping it at 2012 on a 2017 instance?

It feels like this isn't ok - what happens in a couple years when I upgrade this instance a version or two further? At some point I'd imagine that master should be at a more recent compatibility level than 2012.

Comment: You're sort of re-asking the same question you bolded and focused on here [RDS MSSQL in-place upgrade how to update master db compatibility level when rdsa account is db owner](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270942/rds-mssql-in-place-upgrade-how-to-update-master-db-compatibility-level-when-rdsa)